# Application Defined or object Defined Error related to slicers

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I am fairly new to VBA and I am trying to run VBA code to try and select a slicer but I am getting a runtime error 1004 Application Defined or object defined error. I'm not sure if it is due to the name .SlicerItems or if there is something else in the code that is causing this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

SVAL = Format(Date, "ww")
SVAL = Format(Date, "YYYY") & SVAL

Sheets("Summary").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_WK_NBR_F")
    .ClearManualFilter
    For Each oSlicerItem In .SlicerItems
        If oSlicerItem.Name = SVAL Then
            oSlicerItem.Selected = True
        Else
            oSlicerItem.Selected = False
        End If
     Next oSlicerItem
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\brdata\reports\sales\DEPARTMENT_SALES_YTD.xlsx", FileFormat:=51

End Sub
```

the error I am getting is on the line that says

```
For Each oSlicerItem in .SlicerItems
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Excel Slicer]

[image: Slicer Settings]

Comment: Actually running your provided code in a test environment and pivot table, I'm not getting any errors, so the structure is fine. Can you provide a snapshot of your pivot/slicer with any non-critical items blacked out?

Comment: I've added them to the original post